# Django Generic View - ListView from an instance of DetailView

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-generic-views

I am using Generic views `DetailView` and `ListView`

I have three models as such `User`, `Business` and `Invoice`. A User can have multiple businesses can have multiple invoices.

```
#mixins.py
class BusinessOwnerRequiredMixin(object):

    def has_permissions(self):
        obj = self.get_object()
        if isinstance(obj, Business):
        # Assumes that your Article model has a foreign key called `auteur`.
            return obj.owner == self.request.user

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.has_permissions():
            raise PermissionDenied
        return super(BusinessOwnerRequiredMixin, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

```
#views.py
class BusinessDashboard(BusinessOwnerRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Business
    template_name = "business/business-main.html"

class InvoiceListView(BusinessDashboard):
    template_name = "business/purchase/purchase_invoice-main.html"

class InvoiceDetailView(InvoiceListView):
    template_name = "business/purchase/purchase_invoice.html"
```

---

```
#urls.py
path(r'business/<pk>/purchase_invoices/<pid>/',vw.PurchaseInvoiceDetailView.as_view(), name='purchase_invoice'),
path(r'business/<pk>/purchase_invoices/',vw.PurchaseInvoiceListView.as_view(), name='purchase_invoices')
```

What I am looking for is to inherit the ListView of Invoice from DetailView of Business i.e, from an instance of a Business i.e, all invoices of a particular Business must be listed.

How to implement this like:

```
 #views.py
    #views.py
class BusinessDashboard(BusinessOwnerRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Business
    template_name = "business/business-main.html"

class InvoiceListView(BusinessDashboard, ListView):
    model = Invoice
    template_name = "business/purchase/purchase_invoice-main.html"

class InvoiceDetailView(InvoiceListView, DetailView):
    model = Invoice
    template_name = "business/purchase/purchase_invoice.html"
```

But that woin't work, since I am overriding the `model` on each class...

For the url `http://example.com/business/1/invoices/1/`, inside the template I must have a variable with a invoice instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no need for inheritance; you just need to define `get_queryset` to filter the invoices by the business pk.

```
class InvoiceListView(ListView):
    template_name = "business/purchase/purchase_invoice-main.html"

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Invoice.objects.filter(business_id=self.kwargs['pk'])
```

Comment: But, I also want to use the `BusinessOwnerRequiredMixin ` on `InvoiceListView`. Only owner can view the `InvoiceListView ` of that particular business. How to implement this?

Comment: You could implement a simple `get_object` method in this view, to get the Business from the kwargs, then the mixin would just work.

Comment: yeah. Didn't think about it. Thanks.

Comment: Hey I also have a `http://example.com/business/1/invoices/1/`=> `InvoiceDetailView`. If I implement the `get_object` here as well use the `BusinessOwnerRequiredMixin`, this overrides the Invoice object. Any help?